# Find an enum value from a PARTIAL string in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an input in which the user can enter a search criteria and next to it a dropdown to select which field the user is searching against. For string values works great but one of the fields is defined as an enum and the user may choose to just enter part of the search value.

For example, consider:

```
enum DaysOfWeek {
   Monday,
   Tuesday,
   Wednesday,
   Thursday,
   Friday
}
```

The user could just write "Mon" and find all the items that on that particular field the value is DaysOfWeek.Monday.

How can this be accomplished?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to create a collection of mappings.

```js
enum DaysOfWeek {
   Monday,
   Tuesday,
   Wednesday,
   Thursday,
   Friday
}

const dayMappings = [
  { text: 'monday', key: DaysOfWeek.Monday },
  { text: 'tuesday', key: DaysOfWeek.Tuesday },
  { text: 'wednesday', key: DaysOfWeek.Wednesday },
  { text: 'thursday', key: DaysOfWeek.Thursday },
  { text: 'friday', key: DaysOfWeek.Friday }
]

const getDayEnumFromUserInput = (text: string) => {
  return dayMappings.find(m => m.text.startsWith(text.toLowerCase()));
};
```

You could also use `indexOf() >= 0` instead of `startsWith()` in your `find()` predicate. Unfortunately [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) isn't supported in IE.